# Best way to refresh changes in an image

Tags: c#, image

I have a winform c# app.

I am using Emgu for comparing the motion differences between 2 images.

I impose the changes detected onto the 1st image so in affect the first image now looks identical to the second image.

I am overriding the onpaint event of a user control to draw the image.  I have to Invalidate the usercontrol to force the onpaint event.

This works well but the memory still 'spikes' a bit.  Is there a way to invalidate only the pixels that have changed - like regions for instance?

This is my current code:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

        if (CurrentFrame != null)
        {
            pe.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(CurrentFrame, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

The CurrentFrame is a static Bitmap
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried recreating the same control with updated values?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to try to help me.  I edited my post to show the code.  It is a simple as that. Why would destroying and recreating the control be quicker?  Ready to learn :)  thanks

Comment: I answered it that way because destroying control may release some memory and recreating the same will occupy almost the same memory so there will be no memory spike problem. That is what my understanding told me. Hence answered accordingly

Comment: Hi, OK. I could always give a go :). It was more of the case of me understanding and clarifying the suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson yes, there is a way to Invalidate only some region, however you have to determine that region by yourself, you can calculate that `Region` and pass in the `Invalidate` method.

Comment: Hi, yes I was just looking at that.  The only issue is that I can only use 1 region at a time. The way I am thinking is to declare a Region array and enumerate through that 1 at a time. I am just worried that the memory gained from not drawing the entire image is lost by doing the enumeration.  But will not know until I try which is what I am doing now. thanks for your response :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson you can add many Regions to another Region using the `Region.Union` method, after uniting all the Regions into one Region, you can just pass this final Region to the `Invalidate()` method.

Comment: just thought I would give some back.  I did create all the regions OK but as each region 1 pixel width and 1 pixel height the memoery went higher. Which should be as a surprise if I had thought about it 1st. If had an 'aggregator' to l 'lump' regions together I am sure I would get a better result.  Anyone know of an aggregator that is efficent to use in this scenario?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson you don't need to create all the regions together, just create your final region first (call it `finalRegion`), then for each next region (`region1`,`region2`,...), you just pass in the `finalRegion.Union` like this: `finalRegion.Union(region1); finalRegion.Union(region2); ...`

Comment: hi, yes that is what I do but the memory spikes I am afraid.